# Help with moving PictureBox using keys and timers

Tags: c#, timer, key, picturebox

I'm making a shooting game like space invaders. My PictureBox pb won't move using keys and I have a problem on PictureBox pb1, the space disc disappears after a second. It won't move left and right.

Here's my codes so far.

```
namespace SpaceShoot
{
class Shoot
{

    private Form f;
    private Button bLeft, bRight;
    private PictureBox pb;
    private PictureBox pb1;
    private Boolean check = false;
    private int X, Y;
    Timer Clock = new Timer();
    private int k = 0;
    int x = 0;

    public Shoot()
    {
        f = new Form();

        bLeft = new Button();
        bRight = new Button();

        pb = new PictureBox();  //spaceship
        pb1 = new PictureBox(); //spacedisc

        Clock = new Timer();

    }

    public void Launch()
    {

        pb1.Image = new Bitmap("spacedisc.png");
        pb1.SetBounds(20, 20, 120, 70);

        pb1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

        f.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        f.Size = new Size(700, 700);
        f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        f.Controls.Add(pb);
        f.Controls.Add(pb1);

        bLeft.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Space_KeyDown);
        bRight.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Space_KeyDown);

        pb.SetBounds(300, 580, 60, 60);
        pb.Image = new Bitmap("spaceship.png");         

        pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

        Clock = new Timer();
        Clock.Interval = 800;
        Clock.Tick += new EventHandler(Clock_Tick);
        Clock.Start();
        f.ShowDialog();
    }

    public void Clock_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (x = 0; x >= 0; x += 2)
        {
            pb1.Location = new Point(0 + x, 20);
        }
        for (x = 500; x >= 500; x -= 2)
        {
            pb1.Location = new Point(500 - x, 20);
        }
         f.Invalidate();           
    }

    public void Space_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        int x = pb.Location.X;
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            x += 5;
            pb.Location = new Point(300 + x, 580);
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            x -= 5;
            pb.Location = new Point(300 + x, 580);
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

oOo.... where to start? Okay, one thing at a time.

**First** off, you have an infinite loop:

```
            for (x = 0; x >= 0; x += 2)
            {
                pb1.Location = new Point(0 + x, 20);
            }
```

So the app never runs past a single tick.

**Secondly** you're running in a dialog.... which I really don't recommend. Replace:

```
f.ShowDialog();
```

with:

```
Application.Run(f);
```

With your program.cs probably looking something like this:

```
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Shoot shoot = new Shoot();
        shoot.Launch();
```

If you're already within a WinForm application then just .Show() the form and .Hide() any previous forms.

**Thirdly**... and I appreciate you're probably just having fun here... but anyway: this is a pretty bad way to make a game using WinForm. Windows controls are not designed to be used this way and you will eventually run into a number of issues with clipping, transparency and other rendering issues. What I would recommend is to have the game update an image that is painted into the bounds of a control that occupies the entire form. This way you can perform all the rendering in one hit instead of having to rely on lots of individual paint methods of each control you are using. It will also scale better the more sprites you have on screen (as controls are relatively heavy objects).

I highly recommend reading the [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20141230145656/http://bobpowell.net/faqmain.aspx) FAQ on the GDI+. It's the same one that helped me appreciate how to draw nicely in WinForm many years ago. :)

In short:

- Organise your code to create images for each frame of the game
- Create a custom control (an object that inherits from Control) to then render the "current" image into the graphics object (override the OnPaint method to do this) for the control.